# Adjusting in-cockpit view

Tags: controllers, war-thunder

I have issue with in-cockpit look around using the hat-switch on Logitech G940 HOTAS controls in *War Thunder*. If I use the mouse-look (default: press and hold <kbd>C</kbd> key while moving mouse), I can see everything perfectly: including looking behind own tail, and the whole rest of the sphere of view. However, using the hat-switch on the joystick, my FOV is fairly limited: I can see 90° left or right, or 90° up, but I cannot see behind (180°), and I cannot see in three-quarter sectors (left- and right-up forward and back, something like 45° both horizontal and vertical), nor can I see below in any direction except of forward a bit so I can see all of the instrument panel.

The game supports G940 natively, and most of the functions work out of the box, however buggy some of them may be. Controllers are calibrated in the Logitech software. As far as I remember, in *Il-2* hat-switch works all the way around. Is there a way to make it work like so in *War Thunder*? Or is it by design? Would something like using face-tracking software for a web-camera be a better solution anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Setting up the controls in War Thunder can be very difficult because of the sheer number of options that there are. I have a Thrustmaster T16000m joystick and I have a mostly functional controls setup.

If you want to be able to look around with varying degrees of movement rather than by snapping to that 90° position, you need to *enable relative control*. Here's what my setup looks like:

[image: Open in a new tab if you wanna see it bigger]

Make sure you set **Relative Control to Yes**, and **Correction to 0%**. Control sensitivity, step, and multiplier will all change how fast the camera moves, so you can adjust that to your preference. You can set the exact same controls for the Y axis, just change which physical axis you're controlling it with.

Here's the rest of my setup for the view controls:

[image]

Most of these options can be adjusted based on how fast / smooth you want your camera to move. But I wanted to point out one part of the controls that shouldn't be overlooked. At the bottom of the list you can see the controls for **Head Movement**. These are usually only used when you have a head tracking device, but you *can* bind them to keys if you want, and I'll show you why.

Although you can now use the hatswitch to look behind you, many planes dont have a very good view, thanks to the armor plate behind your head, like in the Bf 109s:

[image]

I bound my head movement to the WASD keys so that I could get a little more view behind me.

Here's what you can see when you move your head up, and then to the side:

[image]

[image]

Much better huh? I've found this to be really helpful in battle. As for head tracking, many people will swear by it, but others who are excellent pilots will say you don't need it at all. If you're willing to put in the effort of making or buying one, then by all means go for it, but it's not at all a necessity.